# What are good series to ask about for Summer 2013?

Tags: discussion

The summer season of anime starts soon (most premiers are in July). Currently airing series tend to generate a lot of interest and consequently a lot of traffic, so it would be good if we could get some high-quality questions about them. However, we also need those questions to get answered well, which requires that we have members here who are knowledgeable about such series.

With that in mind, I had the idea of informally polling here on meta to get a sense of what series are good fits for our community. This isn't intended to be used for any official business, but it will help some people (like me) decide what series are good to ask about. Of course, you're welcome to ask about a series even if it isn't here.

**Factoring in expected popularity and our community's strengths, what series from summer 2013 would make good material to ask about?**

For simplicity, let's keep it to one anime per answer. Upvote if you think it's a good choice to ask about. Feel free to leave a comment if you're planning on watching that series, or if you consider yourself especially knowledgeable about it (e.g. you've read the manga). I'm posting this rather early so that there's plenty of time for people to check out the source material, previous seasons, and whatever promotional videos have been released before the season stars.

Click the image below to see the Neregate chart of all anime premiering in summer 2013. As a warning, the chart is large. *(Users with lower bandwidth or not wanting to wait for the image to load can view a textual version [here](http://pastebin.com/SfLyFaR5).)*

[image]

Comment: I am a bit confused here. When you said "good to ask about", do you mean "has potential for interesting question" or "can be answered well"?

Comment: @nhahtdh The goal of this is to get well-answered questions about popular series, since those are our best way to bring in traffic. So, it's primarily in terms of what members of our community are already knowledgeable about, as well as overall popularity. Having potential for interesting questions doesn't hurt either, though. This post is pretty experimental, so feel free to answer on whatever basis you like.

Answer (score 5):

**Monogatari Series Second Season**

[image]

This is the continuation of the popular series of NisiOisiN novels beginning with Bakemonogatari. It's a very popular series, and hence likely to attract lots of visitors. It also is at times fairly confusing, with a good deal of symbolism and artistic liberties, so there's plenty to ask about. Also, including myself, we have at least a couple of users who have read some of the light novels.

[Click here for the PV](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qxCqk3E4QcY)

Answer (score 2):

**Dangan Ronpa**

[image: Dangan Ronpa image]

This series is based off of a game which has a ginormous English fanbase, mostly thanks to a playthrough thread on SA I believe. I expect that the anime will experience decent popularity since fans who don't know Japanese can experience the story "first hand" for the first time.

I don't know too much about the series, but it seems to have a good amount of characters and a complex (or at least more complex than most anime lately...) plot, so it should be full of questions. We could also get new members who have read the playthrough and can answer these questions.

Comment: I'm pretty familiar with the original game, so if the adaptation is pretty faithful I can answer questions about this. I'm not sure if I'll watch the anime though.

Answer (score 2):

**Rozen Maiden**

[image: Rozen Maiden picture]

This franchise is already pretty popular; its previous seasons are even licensed in the US. However, it's been **7 years** since since the previous season, so I'm sure there are people who have forgotten details about the story that the new series may rely on. Additionally, new questions about past seasons' events may arise due to new information presented in the current season.

Answer (score 2):

Can a noob add her 2 cents? I vouch for **Gatchaman Crowds**. It's relationship to the original Gatchaman series (including Gatchaman II and Fighter) are going to raise questions.
Also Tatsunoko has been known to put in cameo appearances of characters from other series. So we can expect some "which series is being referenced here" type questions.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Code Geass Gaiden: Bōkoku no Akito**

[image: Code Geass Gaiden]

This is an OVA spin-off of Code Geass: Lelouch of the Rebellion set on the European warfront. Code Geass is fairly popular and can be confusing, so this might bring in some users.

[Here is the ANN description of the announcement.](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2010-04-22/code-geass-gaiden-bokoku-no-akito-project-announced)

Answer (score 1):

This is a graph showing how Winter anime are received by English-speaking communities, ordered by studio. Any slice is the sum of all MAL, AnimePlanet and ANN members who watched one or more episodes of the show produced by the studio (animation production).

[image: graph]

Then, following anime from AIC, SHAFT and A-1 Pictures is a wise choice, since in the graph the anime of these studio covers about 30% of the total for Winter 2013.

Shows of these studios for Summer 2013 as of the OP list are:

- Gen'ei o Kakeru Taiyou
- Gin no Saji: Silver Spoon
- Servant x Service
- Monogatari Series Second Season

P.A. Works has one show running by now (Red Data Girl) and will present [Uchoten kazoku](http://www.crunchyroll.com/anime-news/2013/06/11-1/video-uchoten-kazoku-exhibition-at-tokyo-anime-center) and this would be my personal choice.

However, *Genshiken Nidaime* has many strong points to be a very interesting series to be covered on Anime & Manga SE: in my country some volumes of the manga are sold out and the series is very well known, and Production IG is a big name too. This is a series talking about an anime and manga circle, so it can starts discussions about [manga-production](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manga-production), [anime-production](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime-production) and [culture](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/culture) like [Bakuman](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bakuman).

Answer (score 0):

**Ro-Kyu-Bu! SS**

[image]

This is a second season of the series [*Ro-Kyu-Bu!*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ro-Kyu-Bu!), a reasonably popular basketball-themed anime. It is a bit esoteric (in terms of its target audience being a bit narrow), but I think it still has the potential to bring in some users. There is also [an OVA](http://myanimelist.net/anime/15807/Ro-Kyu-Bu!:_Tomoka_no_Ichigo_Sundae) due out on June 20.

[Brief ANN announcement](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2012-10-20/ro-kyu-bu-anime-gets-2nd-season)

Answer (score 0):

This is a sort of meta-answer rather than an actual answer. I searched on MAL for all series which will air next season. I then sorted them by number of users listing the series as "plan to watch", and recorded the top 30 (all with over 1000 users). The results are below.

Note, however, that this is just the number of people saying that they plan to watch the series. It's not a terribly good estimate for the actual numbers of viewers. In particular, shows with large existing fanbases are overrated, while sleeper hits won't become clear until we have at least a few episodes to judge by. It also indicates absolutely nothing about our community's strengths or what will make for good questions, just a crude estimate of the overall size of the fanbase.

Sadly, it seems that links don't work inside tables, so I made sure to use the same name as the MAL page.

```
  #  Members   Series Name
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1   13201 High School DxD NEW
  2   12061 Blood Lad
  3   10654 Kami Nomi zo Shiru Sekai: Megami-hen
  4   9929  Free!
  5   9453  Monogatari Series: Second Season
  6   9120  Danganronpa: Kibou no Gakuen to Zetsubou no Koukousei – The Animation
  7   6491  Watashi ga Motenai no wa Dou Kangaetemo Omaera ga Warui!
  8   5378  Fate/kaleid liner Prisma Illya
  9   5471  Kamisama no Inai Nichiyoubi
  10  4406  Choujigen Game Neptune: The Animation
  11  4127  Kimi no Iru Machi
  12  3749  Gin no Saji
  13  3499  Brothers Conflict
  14  3219  Rozen Maiden (2013)
  15  3178  Hakkenden: Touhou Hakken Ibun 2
  16  3137  Makai Ouji: Devils and Realist
  17  2806  Inu to Hasami wa Tsukaiyou
  18  2278  Senki Zesshou Symphogear G: In the Distance, That Day, When the Star Became Music...
  19  1949  Servant x Service
  20  1935  Genei wo Kakeru Taiyou
  21  1917  Kiniro Mosaic
  22  1913  Gatchaman Crowds
  23  1880  Ro-Kyu-Bu! SS
  24  1877  Love Lab
  25  1529  Genshiken Nidaime
  26  1518  Fantasista Doll
  27  1500  Tamayura: More Aggressive
  28  1490  Senyuu. 2
  29  1470  Stella Jogakuin Koutou-ka C³-bu
  30  1099  Kitakubu Katsudou Kiroku
```

Feel free to update this table, but if you do please update the whole table, not just a single series.

Comment: It's a good method Logan, similar to those I used in [my graph here](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/a/616/98) for Winter 2013 (any slice is composed by user following anime from those studios). However, before first episodes are aired you'll get confusing results in my experience. Consider that Maoyu now is the first in the list with about 49,000 members who has the anime in their lists and before airing was 4th with about 5,000 members.